# How to translate Angular-UI-Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

The documentation for the datepicker ([Angle-UI-BootStrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap)) reports:

> Everything is formatted using the [date filter](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.filter%3adate) and thus is also
>   localized.

Checking the documentation for the [date filter](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/api/ng.filter%3adate) can have access to the concept of [i18n and i10n](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/docs/guide/i18n) for AngularJs. However, the two approaches which are provided, can not be used in my application. The two approaches are:

> 1. **Pre-bundled rule sets**
> 2. **Including locale js script in index.html page**

In my application, I check the language of the client after he had performed login. So my index.html page is already created and configured.

There is no other way to translate the datepicker? A dynamically way... something like changing a value of the $scope that alters the interface performing the translation of the component?

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cWGahX?p=preview) demonstrating the approach of introducing in the index.html the translation for pt-BR.

**Update:**
I asked this question in an [issue of the Angle-UI-Bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/777), and here is the response I received from @bekos:

> @ThCC The real problem is that you cannot change your $locale during
>   runtime, or at least I don't know of a way to do this. Even if you
>   solve the problem with the datepicker, you will still have problem in
>   every other filter that is locale dependent, like currency. I think it
>   is better to ask a more general question in the AngularJS issues.

If anyone has another solution is always welcome. If I get a solution I will return here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS/Angular-ui-bootstrap Changing language used by the datePicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671887/angularjs-angular-ui-bootstrap-changing-language-used-by-the-datepicker)

Comment: @redben The question may be the same, but the context that led the formulation of the question is different.

Comment: Hello. Is there any way to change the language without adding the specific language script ?

Answer (score 9):

Someone said [The real problem is that you cannot change your $locale during runtime]. In fact you can. You can see a working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7LsfG5D28Y7jB9vhEiQV?p=preview).

Comment: the punker you reference is empty!

Comment: @ra00l Strange... Here is another [link](https://github.com/stahe/angular-ui-bootstrap-datepicker-with-locale-updated-on-the-fly)

Comment: Instead of change the angular locale files as you do in your plunker, you can use Angular Dynamic Locale (https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale), but, to make it work with the datepicker, you need to change the model to apply the changes (as you do in your plunker).

Comment: This doesn't work when date is null - for example when you click in the popup on the clear button.

Comment: This would work, if you'd manually called the `ngModel.$render()` - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own directive like this:

```
angular
    .module('myApp.common')
    .directive('datepickerPopupWrap', datepickerPopupWrap);

datepickerPopupWrap.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

function datepickerPopupWrap($rootScope, $compile) {

    return {

        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',

        link: function($scope, $element, attrs, ngModel) {
            // Force popup rerender whenever locale changes
            $rootScope.$on('localeChanged', ngModel.$render);
        }
    };

}
```

The directive name **must be** `datepickerPopupWrap`, so it's executed together with the default ui-bootstrap directive that renders the popup.

Then, whenever you change the locale with [`angular-dynamic-locale`](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale), do this:

```
tmhDynamicLocale.set(languageKey).then(function() {

    // Set the language in angular-translate
    $translate.use(languageKey);

    // Broadcast the event so datepickers would rerender
    $rootScope.$broadcast('localeChanged');
});
```

Comment: Hello. Is there any way to change the language without adding the specific language script ?

Answer (score 1):

I was not happy using the given approaches, so I figured out this one by using [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) and the possibility, to overwrite the angular-ui-bootstrap-templates like this (Source from `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`):

For `uib/template/datepicker/day.html`:

```
angular.module("uib/template/datepicker/day.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("uib/template/datepicker/day.html",
        "<table class=\"uib-daypicker\" role=\"grid\" aria-labelledby=\"{{::uniqueId}}-title\" aria-activedescendant=\"{{activeDateId}}\">\n" +
        "  <thead>\n" +
        "    <tr>\n" +
        "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left uib-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></i></button></th>\n" +
        "      <th colspan=\"{{::5 + showWeeks}}\"><button id=\"{{::uniqueId}}-title\" role=\"heading\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\" ng-disabled=\"datepickerMode === maxMode\" tabindex=\"-1\"><strong>{{ title | uppercase | localizeMonth }}</strong></button></th>\n" +
        "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right uib-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></i></button></th>\n" +
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "    <tr>\n" +
        "      <th ng-if=\"showWeeks\" class=\"text-center\"></th>\n" +
        "      <th ng-repeat=\"label in ::labels track by $index\" class=\"text-center\"><small aria-label=\"{{::label.full}}\">{{ ('DAY_' + label.abbr | uppercase) | translate}}</small></th>\n" +
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "  </thead>\n" +
        "  <tbody>\n" +
        "    <tr class=\"uib-weeks\" ng-repeat=\"row in rows track by $index\">\n" +
        "      <td ng-if=\"showWeeks\" class=\"text-center h6\"><em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em></td>\n" +
        "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row\" class=\"uib-day text-center\" role=\"gridcell\"\n" +
        "        id=\"{{::dt.uid}}\"\n" +
        "        ng-class=\"::dt.customClass\">\n" +
        "        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm\"\n" +
        "          uib-is-class=\"\n" +
        "            'btn-info' for selectedDt,\n" +
        "            'active' for activeDt\n" +
        "            on dt\"\n" +
        "          ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\"\n" +
        "          ng-disabled=\"::dt.disabled\"\n" +
        "          tabindex=\"-1\"><span ng-class=\"::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}\">{{::dt.label}}</span></button>\n" +
        "      </td>\n" +
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "  </tbody>\n" +
        "</table>\n" +
        "");
}]);
```

For `uib/template/datepicker/month.html`:

```
angular.module("uib/template/datepicker/month.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("uib/template/datepicker/month.html",
        "<table class=\"uib-monthpicker\" role=\"grid\" aria-labelledby=\"{{::uniqueId}}-title\" aria-activedescendant=\"{{activeDateId}}\">\n" +
        "  <thead>\n" +
        "    <tr>\n" +
        "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left uib-left\" ng-click=\"move(-1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left\"></i></button></th>\n" +
        "      <th><button id=\"{{::uniqueId}}-title\" role=\"heading\" aria-live=\"assertive\" aria-atomic=\"true\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title\" ng-click=\"toggleMode()\" ng-disabled=\"datepickerMode === maxMode\" tabindex=\"-1\"><strong>{{title}}</strong></button></th>\n" +
        "      <th><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right uib-right\" ng-click=\"move(1)\" tabindex=\"-1\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right\"></i></button></th>\n" +
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "  </thead>\n" +
        "  <tbody>\n" +
        "    <tr class=\"uib-months\" ng-repeat=\"row in rows track by $index\">\n" +
        "      <td ng-repeat=\"dt in row\" class=\"uib-month text-center\" role=\"gridcell\"\n" +
        "        id=\"{{::dt.uid}}\"\n" +
        "        ng-class=\"::dt.customClass\">\n" +
        "        <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\"\n" +
        "          uib-is-class=\"\n" +
        "            'btn-info' for selectedDt,\n" +
        "            'active' for activeDt\n" +
        "            on dt\"\n" +
        "          ng-click=\"select(dt.date)\"\n" +
        "          ng-disabled=\"::dt.disabled\"\n" +
        "          tabindex=\"-1\"><span ng-class=\"::{'text-info': dt.current}\">{{ ('MONTH_' + dt.label | uppercase) | translate }}</span></button>\n" +
        "      </td>\n" +
        "    </tr>\n" +
        "  </tbody>\n" +
        "</table>\n" +
        "");
}]);
```

You also need to extend your language file by (this is for the german language):

```
, 'MONTH_JANUARY':                  'Januar'
, 'MONTH_FEBRUARY':                 'Februar'
, 'MONTH_MARCH':                    'März'
, 'MONTH_APRIL':                    'April'
, 'MONTH_MAY':                      'May'
, 'MONTH_JUNE':                     'June'
, 'MONTH_JULY':                     'July'
, 'MONTH_AUGUST':                   'August'
, 'MONTH_SEPTEMBER':                'September'
, 'MONTH_OCTOBER':                  'October'
, 'MONTH_NOVEMBER':                 'November'
, 'MONTH_DECEMBER':                 'December'
```

And since the current month of the datepicker is orignally rendered as `{{title}}` provied by `scope.title = dateFilter(this.activeDate, this.formatDayTitle);` (line 2216 in `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`), you have to load a filter to localize the current month (Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939288/angular-filter-to-replace-all-underscores-to-spaces)):

```
/* global app */
app.filter('localizeMonth', function($interpolate)
{
    return function (input)
    {
        return input
            .replace(/JANUARY/g,   $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_JANUARY\'   | translate}}'))
            .replace(/FEBRUARY/g,  $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_FEBRUARY\'  | translate}}'))
            .replace(/MARCH/g,     $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_MARCH\'     | translate}}'))
            .replace(/APRIL/g,     $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_APRIL\'     | translate}}'))
            .replace(/MAY/g,       $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_MAY\'       | translate}}'))
            .replace(/JUNE/g,      $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_JUNE\'      | translate}}'))
            .replace(/JULY/g,      $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_JULY\'      | translate}}'))
            .replace(/AUGUST/g,    $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_AUGUST\'    | translate}}'))
            .replace(/SEPTEMBER/g, $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_SEPTEMBER\' | translate}}'))
            .replace(/OCTOBER/g,   $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_OCTOBER\'   | translate}}'))
            .replace(/NOVEMBER/g,  $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_NOVEMBER\'  | translate}}'))
            .replace(/DECEMBER/g,  $interpolate('{{ \'MONTH_DECEMBER\'  | translate}}'))
        ;
    };
});
```

I think this solution is at least as ugly as the other hacks that were invented here, but you don't have to trigger redraws or similar things by yourself.