# AngularJS/Angular-ui-bootstrap Changing language used by the datePicker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use the datePicker documented [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

However, no direct option allows to change the language, **English** by default.

I find a the documentation of the widget provided without angular directive, and it provides a nice way to achieve it:

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/i18n.html

Is there an easy way, avoiding to tweak the original directive's source code, to change it?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you are using the DatePicker form angular-ui simply add the localized js file in the header of your page. An example would be :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/i18n/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
```

You can see a working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZrfDlSROZxKrOAiA0PXp?p=preview)

Comment: This doesn't translate the action buttons text when using the popup. To translate it, you must also configure the datepickerPopupConfig global objetct : http://plnkr.co/edit/g5uxqcJkhqbQRKmLI2Zj?p=preview

Comment: When using bower, [bower install angular-i18n](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n)

Comment: remember to change the localization cdn url to match your angular version

Answer (score 18):

First, you have to load your locales ([get them here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale)) script after angular in index.html:

```
 <script src="angular.js"></script>
 <script src="angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
```

After that, the days and months are localised but you need to translate the buttons by yourself adding parameters inside the datepicker input tag:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy"
ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2042-04-02'"
datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
ng-required="true" 
current-text="Tonight" clear-text="Reset" close-text="Exit" />
```

Comment: is it possible to download a single locale using bower?

Comment: datepicker labels works but localizations doesnt work. can you help us please ? I added angular-locale_tr-tr.js to index.html but no change in picker.

Answer (score 4):

You can find locale js files latest version with this link.

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-i18n

Also, if you want to translate datepicker action buttons(like 'Close') globaly, you can add this code for global config.

```
//DatePicker -> uibDatepickerConfig
//DatePickerPopup -> uibDatepickerPopupConfig
app.config(['uibDatepickerPopupConfig', function(uibDatepickerPopupConfig) {
uibDatepickerPopupConfig.closeText = 'Close';
uibDatepickerPopupConfig.currentText = 'Today';
uibDatepickerPopupConfig.clearText = 'Clear';
}]);
```

Comment: With globaly the problem is, that you cannot display the buttons in different languages during runtime.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my project as we reload the page on language change and this saved me from having to wrap the date-picker in my own directive