# Language in Angular datepicker directive for bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-directive

I am using the Angular directive for Bootstrap datepicker: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

I can not find any documentation saying i can set a default language on it. The date format is easy enough to change, but i can't set the language to norwegian so that the months, or days are displayed in norwegian instead of english. Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Thanks in advance.

-L

Comment: I think your question was already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671887/angularjs-angular-ui-bootstrap-changing-language-used-by-the-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Edminsson. I looked at that link earlier, but for some reason i didn't find it relevant to me. (Must have been before i had my morning coffee)

Here's the solution: [AngularJS/Angular-ui-bootstrap Changing language used by the datePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671887/angularjs-angular-ui-bootstrap-changing-language-used-by-the-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I'm not sure if it helps. But somewhere is pointed out, that you can use the standard localization of angular.

Please refer to this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n).

Comment: It will help, datepicker uses the date filter which uses localization. Just including the Norwegian i18n should do the trick: https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n/blob/master/angular-locale_no-no.js