# Change language in ui.bootstrap.datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I was trying to make the calendar info to be shown in Ukrainian language, so at first I looked through this and hoped that I would just override tha template:

```
angular.module("uib/template/datepicker/datepicker.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("uib/template/datepicker/datepicker.html",
    "<div class=\"uib-datepicker\" ng-switch=\"datepickerMode\" role=\"application\" ng-keydown=\"keydown($event)\">\n" +
    "  <uib-daypicker ng-switch-when=\"day\" tabindex=\"0\"></uib-daypicker>\n" +
    "  <uib-monthpicker ng-switch-when=\"month\" tabindex=\"0\"></uib-monthpicker>\n" +
    "  <uib-yearpicker ng-switch-when=\"year\" tabindex=\"0\"></uib-yearpicker>\n" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "");
}]);
```

When I found nothing there, I searched in the *datepicker.js* hoping to find some arrays with the name of months and days that I could override, but I found nothing.I have no idea how to do this, and can't find appropriate solution here. I would be very grateful if you tell me (or show answered question which I couldn't find) how to do this, using minimum hacks and mocks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can add the localized js file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676300/3504957) to your scripts.  [This](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) should help you find the correct file.

Comment: Glad I could help :)