# Cannot read property 'join' of undefined when using Angular UI bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

This link exactly discusses the issue: [Angular UI Bootstrap issue Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5439) . But I'm unable to understand what is the solution from the discussion. I tried to add the ngLocale by referencing the link and injecting as a dependency in the 'app' that I created but still the issue exists.

Comment: From a comment of the post you linked.
```In my case, i was using angular-locale en-us, same name module , I uninstalled it and downloaded the angular-i18n and everything worked
```

Comment: I am using this angular locale https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.3.9/angular-locale_en-us.min.js, it has both the words i18n and en_us.

Comment: I am using 1.3.9 of everything by the way, Angular, ng-Route, ng-Animate ..

Comment: Could you please provide the Github's question body on your question?

Comment: Do you mean my code?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are using a wrong resource file, this question explains how to implements and where to download the correct resources file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671887/angularjs-angular-ui-bootstrap-changing-language-used-by-the-datepicker