# Angular filter to replace all underscores to spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I need a filter to replace all the underscores to spaces in a string

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`string.replace` not only accepts string as first argument but also it accepts regex as first argument. So put `_` within regex delimiters `/` and aslo add   `g` modifier along with that. `g` called global modifier which will do the replacement globally.

```
App.filter('underscoreless', function () {
  return function (input) {
      return input.replace(/_/g, ' ');
  };
});
```

Comment: This fail if `input` isn't a string, or if `input` is null or undefined.

Comment: simple, just use an if stmt for condition checking.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a generic replace filter alternative

```
App.filter('strReplace', function () {
  return function (input, from, to) {
    input = input || '';
    from = from || '';
    to = to || '';
    return input.replace(new RegExp(from, 'g'), to);
  };
});
```

Use it as follows in your HTML:

```
{{ addText | strReplace:'_':' ' }}
```

Minor note: Any HTML tags in the `to` parameter will cause the expression to fail due to Angular content security rules.

Comment: Where shud I add App.filter code ? and Which version of angular is this..

Comment: This is for AngularJS 1.x. `App` here represents the object you get back from creating your Angular app as follows: `var App = angular.module('myApp', ['some-dependency', 'some-other-dependency']);`

Answer (score 7):

In some case, you can use `split()` function.
.replace  function is not compliant with regexp syntax (i.e. `.replace(/,/g,'\n')` syntax)

Full syntax:
`{{myVar.toString().split(',').join('\n')}}`

> `.toString()` function is in case myVar is not typed as String in typescript.

Comment: This is the perfect answer, simple and optimized.

Answer (score 1):

There is a easyer method:

You could replace it inline without a defined filter. This is the way.

This example its for replace just in the view.

```
{{ value.replace(/_/g, ' ') }}
```

I hope its could help in a simple change, if you want to change in more places, use the filter.

Comment: BratisLatas I liked your method, however it appears to only replace only one instance, not multiple.

Comment: I don't think that's a valid angular expression. It does work if the first argument is a string, but if using the regular expression, I get `syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary expression`.

Comment: Works well for single character replacement

Answer (score 1):

This simple function can do it:

```
public getCleanedString(cadena) {
    cadena = cadena.replace(/_/g, ' ');
    return cadena;
  }
```

Comment: What question are you answering? They want to replace underscore with space.

Answer (score 0):

this is i used in angularjs 1.4.7

```
<li ng-show="filter.degree.length"> 
    <label>Search by Degree :- </label> {{
        filter.degree.toString().split('|').join(', ')
    }} 
</li>
```