# Angular template variable replace markup on the fly

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a heavy dataset.

so I am placing a nested variable inside a table

```
{{entry.text}}
```

but this can have several names like

Clare Butterfield /n/r Barry Burton

--
really I want to replace the carriage returns with a br tag

so each name goes on another line

```
{{(entry.text).replace("/n", "<br>")}}
```

Comment: Can you post your data?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two pieces to complete this:

1) A filter that will take in the text and replace `/n` with `<br/>`, and

2) The ng-bind-html directive to get angular to use that `<br/>` instead of just displaying `Clare Butterfield <br/> Barry Burton`

in the end your html will look something like this:

```
<span ng-bind-html="::entry.text | newLineFilter"/>
```

For an example of a similar filter to what you need, see this SO question here:
[Angular filter to replace all underscores to spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939288/angular-filter-to-replace-all-underscores-to-spaces)

For the ngBindHTML directive, see here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

any questions?

p.s. since your data-set is large you may notice that I added 2 colons in the example above to indicate that it's using one-time binding. This will prevent angular from recalculating the value too often and save on performance. Those aren't strictly necessary, so if you find your text is not updating when you expect it to, just remove them.

Comment: App.filter('underscoreless', function () {
  return function (input) {
      return input.replace(/_/g, ' ');
  };
});  --- we put this in the controller?

Comment: No, it would be separate to the controller, but registered in a similar way. For example you'd register a controller like `App.controller('MyController', function(){...`.
`App` would be called something else in your code.

Comment: There's another example of creating filter at the bottom of this page: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp

Comment: and in your case you wouldn't name your filter `underscoreless`. I used `newLineFilter` in the answer I gave, but you could call it anything you like.

Comment: <td width="50%" ng-bind-html="entry.text | newLineFilter"></td>  and in the js  module.filter 'newLineFilter', -> #() ->
  (str) ->
    return str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,"<br />")